# .net : which automation framework is suitable for MVC model for web automation?

Tags: automated-testing, browser-automation

Right now, i am working as a manual tester and need to start an automation tool to test the web application based on dot net (MVC). Please suggest an automation tool and what environment required to start automation with the help of suggested tool.

Comment: what are your test objectives? What are your deliverable under test? What are your testing environment?

Comment: Yes YuZhang. Mohan - great if you can add or if not any specific requirements then I have enlisted few frameworks below, chk.

Comment: This time, we are only looking to test the GUI, functional,perfomance,cross browser testing of web application.

Comment: and i found that most of the tools are working mainly focus on unit testing. and the most important is that our client requirement changes frequently.

Comment: good to see details. Mohan - I have updated my answer, check.

Comment: variants of this question are asked weekly or more. Please do your homework before asking questions. Google is your friend.

Answer (score 1):

You can use selenium, its an open source for web application automation, supports java,c# and many other languages. It works on windows and linux environment, You can use editors such as eclipse or IntelliJ of respective environment

Answer (score 1):

When you are looking for Web automation, you have many options to choose:

1. Selenium [Most famous one]
2. Capybara
3. Robot
4. WATIR
5. TestStack.White
6. Sahi
7. Ranorex Studio
8. QF-Test

Pick which suits your requirements closely and start automating !

**Adding after you mentioned objectives:**

**Selenium:** I will recommend to go with when not having special and outstanding requirement to automate like mainly which close to limitations of selenium.

**1. Awesome community support:**
- There are many tools at disposal for users of Selenium. 
- Your tests can be run as well as recorded with the help of Firefox plugins.

**2. Very easy for Newbie:**
- Saving the best for last, this is a major reason that many testers choose this tool. 
- It is extremely easy for working on and simple and easy to install.
- Many things can be done in a straightforward manner, including integration with other frameworks or languages. 
- Editing existing commands, deleting or inserting commands can be done very easily as well.

**3. Select any language you love:**

- This is a huge advantage since you can reap multiple benefits from several sources.
- You can choose the language in which you are most comfortable

**4. Open source:**
- Adopting this open source tool means that the overall cost of testing will be quite low.

**5. Supports several test frameworks:** 
- The tool is often known as a kind of GUI driving library, apart from being a simple testing tool. 
- Several frameworks are supported by it such as TestNG, JUnit, PHPUnit, etc.

**6. Single script, multiple browsers:**
- A huge benefit with this testing is that you need one time scripting and then that script can be used on several browsers. 
- While the features as well as benefits may not be same but you can save a huge amount of trouble.

**7. AJAX support:**
- AJAX technologies are strongly supported by Selenium. 
- While working on a browser the application under tests and the test case are driven by technologies that function side by side.

**8.Remote Control/Selenium Grid:**

- The remote control server of Selenium allows automation testers to create a test infrastructure that is spread across multiple locations (including cloud) to drive the scripts on a large set of browsers.

**9. Continuous Integration:** 
- Selenium can be integrated with Jenkins or Hudson for continuous integration.

**10. Mobile extension too available:**
- Appium is extension of selenium which can be for mobile automation.

Please add your point in above list !!

Answer (score 1):

There are number of tools are available.

Preferably **Selenium** and **NUnit** or WatiN.

- Selenium is pure open source, freeware and portable tool.
- Selenium supports variety of languages that include Java, Perl, Python, C#, Ruby, Groovy, Java Script, and VB Script. etc.